# Implementing static members of template classes over multiple DLLs

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, dll, dynamic-linking

I have two DLLs - Master.dll and Slave.dll.
In Master.dll, I define a template class:

```
// MyClass.hpp

#include <vector>

#define EXPORT __declspec( dllexport )

template< int num, typename ... args >
class EXPORT MyClass {
private:
    static MyClass* Instance;

public:
    std::vector< void* > Callbacks;
    static MyClass* GetInstance() { 
        if ( Instance == nullptr ) {
            Instance = new MyClass();
        }
        return Instance;
    }
};

// Initialize the static member
template< int num, typename ... args >
MyClass< num, args >* MyClass< num, args >::Instance;
```

In Slave.dll, I use the template class like so:

```
// SlaveImpl.cpp

#include "MyClass.hpp"
#define EXPORT __declspec( dllimport )

void SomeFunction() {
    auto inst = MyClass<1, int, float>::GetInstance();
    inst->Callbacks.push_back( (void*)0 );

    std::cout << inst << std::endl;
}
```

I then try to access it again in Master.dll:

```
// SomeMasterFile.cpp

void SomeMasterFunction {
    auto inst = MyClass<1, int, float>::GetInstance();
    std::cout << inst << " - " << inst->Callbacks.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Then I compare the two console results, the addresses are different, and the size of the `Callbacks` vector is 0:

```
4E142056
4F5262A1 - 0
```

How can I make both of the DLLs use the same pointer, so that my Master.dll can access the same `Callbacks` vector as Slave.dll?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? How many times does the line `Instance = new MyClass();` gets executed?

Comment: You cannot export a template from a DLL - there's simply nothing to export, a template is simply a bunch of C++ code up until the moment it's actually used and template parameters become known. Think about it - at the time Master.dll is compiled and linked, neither compiler nor linker can possibly know that another binary would, at some later time, want to instantiate `MyClass<1, int, float>` specifically. Exporting a variable of this specific type would require clairvoyance.

Comment: You should, however, be able to export individual specializations of a template - like this: `template class EXPORT MyClass<1, int, float>;` Though this kinda defeats the point of making `MyClass` a template in the first place.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik So I would have to export these specializations in the Master.dll hpp file? Or in the Slave.dll .cpp file? Or in both?

Comment: You decide which DLL you want to export from, and which DLL you want to consume. Then use the standard macro trick to have those specializations marked `__declspec(dllexport)` in the former, and `__declspec(dllimport)` in the latter.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik This works fine on Linux though (provided that I instantiate `MyClass<1, int, float>::Instance` in every shlib).

Comment: @yugr Shared objects on Linux work differently than DLLs on Windows. I don't know the details (I'm a Windows guy myself), just the fact that the model is fundamentally different. Something about doing a full linker pass at load time. In any case, "but it works on Linux" is not a useful argument when you are trying to solve a problem on Windows.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik ""but it works on Linux" is not a useful argument" - well, your arguments weren't Windows-specific so I decided to point this out (and "exporting a variable of this specific type would require clairvoyance" is not a useful argument either).

Comment: @yugr That comment was about exporting a template as a whole, which makes no sense. You state that it works on Linux provided you explicitly instantiate all the template specializations you need to use; by doing this, you supply the missing information, making clairvoyance unnecessary. Explicit instantiations can be made to work on Windows, too.